# Как установить и использовать TensorFlow и Keras без CUDA?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, cuda, gpu

Пытаюсь установить TensorFlow и Keras пытаюсь импортировать(import tensorflow) и получаю следующую ошибку:

```
2022-11-08 22:32:36.638616: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
```

Я выяснил что требуется установка CUDA.
Но есть проблема: программа, которую я разрабатываю будет использоваться на разных компьютерах в корпоративной сети без интернета. Нет возможности везде установить CUDA.
Можно ли как-то использовать tensorflow без установки CUDA и других дополнительных драйверов? Есть ли какие-нибудь варианты? Если видели где-нибудь решение данной проблемы - поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: А как вы их ставили? Мне кажется там на этапе установки можно выбрать версию, хотя не помню точно

Comment: Я ставил через pip install tensorflow. Просто не знаю какая мне версия нужна. Есть версии, который без CUDA работают?

Comment: Так, я, похоже, был не прав. Всё регулируется переменными окружения. Посмотрите ответы тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690598/can-keras-with-tensorflow-backend-be-forced-to-use-cpu-or-gpu-at-will